# Issue (maybe) with the code for putting message on the queue

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have this code to put message on the queue

```
 public class AzureQueueService : IAzureQueueService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private static string azureServiceBusString = null;

        public AzureQueueService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            azureServiceBusString = "connString";
        }

        public async Task SendMessageAsync<T>(T serviceBusMessage, string queueName)
        {
            // since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
            await using var queueClient = new ServiceBusClient(azureServiceBusString);

            // create the sender
            ServiceBusSender sender = queueClient.CreateSender(queueName);

            string messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(serviceBusMessage);
            var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

            // send the message
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

In my startup file I am doing this

```
services.AddTransient<IAzureQueueService, Core.Services.AzureQueueService>();
```

And I am using it like this

```
var queue = new AzureQueueService(config);
await queue.SendMessageAsync(message, "emailqueue");
```

Could this lead to memory leakage? I mean should I instantiate the ServiceBusClient in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd be looking to set up dependency injection for the ServiceBusClient. As per the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme#client-lifetime) (for 7.8.x)

> The ServiceBusClient, senders, receivers, and processors are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime of the application, which is best practice when messages are being sent or received regularly. They are responsible for efficient management of network, CPU, and memory use, working to keep usage low during periods of inactivity.

Also, see [Best Practises for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2)

Comment: I do not understand that. I can share more code so that maybe it is easy for you to suggest any improvements.

Comment: What @AdaTheDev is trying to say is that based the recommendations by Microsoft, you should not be creating an instance of `ServiceBusClient` on each request as it is an expensive and time consuming operation. Instead you should instantiate it once and inject it via dependency injection wherever it is needed.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri, what I am not understanding is how to inject it when it is using await keyword? Could it be possible with a small code sample? I could not a code sample on Minrosofts website as well

Comment: @mohsinali1317 your "await using..." line would go completely. Add an extra ServiceBusClient parameter to the constuctor and assign that to a new class-level variable, like you're doing with _config already. Then, just use that inside your SendMessagesAsync method

Comment: @AdaTheDev thanks a lot for that. I was confused about the await using.